# Keep tcp connection open until disconnect Android

Tags: android, tcp

I am currently programming vor Android. I'm using C2DM service to send an notification to my application.

When I answer the notification I want to make an connection to a server wich send images continiously everytime I send an http get.

Can I do this using an Asynctask with an while(!userDisconnect)? Or could i check when the Asynctask is completed and do it again? I'm not sure, i'm thinking that it will run ery slow with an while loop?

Comment: I would try that first and let us know how it goes. Also if you are operating inside an activity or service you can override onDestroy() or finish() then call .cancel() on your AsyncTask. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html I think you're heading in the right direction. Keep us informed on how it goes.

Comment: I've tried it that way but I get a lot of errors when I want to run my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer myself:

```
private OnClickListener getlistener = new OnClickListener() {

public void onClick(View v) {
    mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
    mHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 1000);

}
};

private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
      if (response != null)
      {
          getal++;
          response.setText("Hallo" + getal);
          new NetworkTask().execute();
          //network();
       Log.i("Runnable", "OKE");
       mHandler.postAtTime(this, SystemClock.uptimeMillis() + 100);
      }
      else
      {
          Log.i("Runnable", "NULL");
      }
   }
};
```